# Reading the StandardOutput when a process is launched using PsExec.exe (sysinternals)

Tags: c#, .net

I am calling an exe in remote computer using PsExec.exe.
The exe in remote computer performs some action and displays the output in console.
Everything works fine until I tried to redirect the output. The code is as follows,

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = "PsExec.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = "\\\\servername \"C:\\PROGRA~1\\myapp\\app.exe\"";
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
{
string outPutString = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The line `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` hangs and does nothing. 
So, how to read the StandardOutput when a process is launched using PsExec.exe?